# Why is Adobe Premiere Pro / Adobe Media Encoder freezing my computer when rendering?

Tags: premiere, hardware, performance

This is happening when rendering lasts longer than ~20-30  mins.
I've tried checking the temperatures, they are holding steady at a maximum of 45 Celsius (on both CPU and GPU).
Freezes computer completely (no response to mouse/keyboard, image is frozen).
I really need help with this as I plan to make videos a lot.
I doubt its the memory (I have a new Corsair Vengeance memory), thinking It might be the power supply (its 500W, claimed to be OK for GTX 650 Ti + Core i3-3220), Zalman ZM500

Comment: How much memory? More than 4 GB? Assuming you have a 64 bit architecture too. Also, please describe the time line as in how many video tracks, how many audio tracks, and types of effects. All of this would be useful to understand demand vs. resources.

Comment: Have you tried limiting memory and rendering cores?  Are you using the latest compatible drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: I have 8 GB of memory (OS is Windows 7 64bit), 6 of which being used by Premiere.
Effects: only a title. 4 tracks, 2 of which are being used (one for video, one for title). 1-4 videos on the video track. Videos taken by Fraps, 1680x1050. Videos checked, not broken or something. Renders perfectly with quality set to Good (taking 20 minutes or so), but fails to render at Best quality.
Yes, I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest driver (320.49)

Comment: When the computer freezes, have you let it go for another 5 minutes to see if it gets moving again? Otherwise, I think that since it only does this at the 'best' setting, you likely have a resource issue.

Comment: filzilla, tried giving it some time, does not unfreeze
And I'm actually thinking that it depends on how much time it renders. I remember trying to render a longer video with good quality, and it still froze.

Comment: If you can, a sure way to tell if your machine is resource bound, test the same render on an identical machine but with 16 GB to 24 GB of memory. If it does not freeze on this other machine then you know you will need more memory on your machine.